# How to tell spring-kafka consumer to stop consuming, at runtime?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka v2.5.2, with KafkaListener annotations.

At runtime, I would like be able to send a signal to a consumer to stop consuming.

I see the `autoStartup` parameter but it seems to work only for the initialization and cannot be changed after.

I see the methode close() of the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry...

Do you have suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Give each listener an `id` attribute; you can then use the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean to get a reference the listener container which you can then start and stop: `getListenerContainer("myId").stop()`.

This is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle).

Comment: Thanks for response. Is the "id" field mandatory ? I thought to create a rest operation which makes the start/stop methods, and call this api only on the broker I want to perform the change.

Comment: It's not mandatory, but it makes it easier to find the listener (if you have multiple). If you only have one, or you can tell which one you want to stop some other way (e.g. by topic name) you can call `getListenerContainers()` and iterate over them.